# Can you load only a smaller rectangular portion of a larger on-disk image into memory?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

On iOS and most mobile devices there is a restriction on the size of the image that you can load, due to memory contraints.  Is it possible to have a large image on disk (say 5,000 pixels by 5,000 pixels) but only read a smaller rectangle within that image (say 100x100) into memory for display?

In other words, do you need to load the entire image into memory if you just want to see a small subsection of it? If it's possible to load just the smaller portion, how can we do this?

This way, one could save a lot of space like spritesheets do for repetitive content. It would be important to note that the overall goal is to minimize the file size so the large image should be compressed with jpeg or png or some other kind of compression. I suspect video formats are like this because you never load an entire video into the memory.

Comment: What are you doing with a 5k x 5k image? Also, what format is your file in?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have not utilized the techniques, you might find the following Apple Sample useful:

[LargeImageDownsizing Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011173)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something with mapped `NSData` like this:

```
UIImage *pixelDataForRect(NSString *fileName, const CGRect pixelRect)
{
    // get the pixels from that image
    uint32_t width = pixelRect.size.width;
    uint32_t height = pixelRect.size.height;

    // create the context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
    CGContextRef bitMapContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(bitMapContext, flipVertical);

    // render the image (assume PNG compression)
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef) [NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:fileName]);
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, YES, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    uint32_t imageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    uint32_t imageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(-pixelRect.origin.x, -((imageHeight - pixelRect.origin.y) - height), imageWidth, imageHeight);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitMapContext, drawRect, image);

    CGImageRelease(image);

    UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return retImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using UIScrollView with CATiledLayer.

Check out the "Designing Apps with Scroll Views presentation from WWDC 2010 for a description of how to do this:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

The idea is to take your large image and chop it down into tiles, and then use a UIScrollView to provide your user with a scrollable view of the image, only loading those sections of the image that are necessary based on the position of the scrollview.  This is accomplished using CATiledLayer.